# Automatically add remotes that do not exist based on a pattern

Tags: git, pull-request

I'm working with a large open-source project on GitHub, and will need to test lots of pull-requests by pulling down their code locally. I'd love to be able to hook into git somehow so that when I type `git fetch someUser`, if there is no origin named `someUser`, a new origin is added at `git@github.com:someUser/repoName.git`.

Is there such a way to intercept git's operations? Is there a script out there that does this? If not it's not the end of the world, and may prompt me to look into git's insides a bit more to see if I can make it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has a cli tool that augments git with some GitHub specific operations and functionality. One of them is precisely what you're looking for. Check out [hub](http://hub.github.com/#maintainer)

Comment: That's fantastic, I had no idea it existed. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I can accept now. I swear I can't usually accept answers for some period of time.